# My prisoners won't use my canteen

Tags: prison-architect

Recently I've bought Prison Architect, and I'm making a prison. I've built a canteen and kitchen and assigned prisoners to the canteen. The problem is, my prisoners won't go to the canteen to eat, even when the regime says it's time for them to eat. I don't know what to do anymore because they're all starving to death and starting riots.

[image: screenshot of described issue above]

Comment: Does it say if prisoners are assigned? Or does it say none are assigned?

Comment: It's quite possible you disallowed them from leaving their cell or that the canteen is staff only somehow. As Tim S. said, can you please post a screenshot?

Comment: I've actually started another prison now, but I'm getting the same problem. I haven't added prisoners yet because I wanted to finish all the cells and canteen first. http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=642747405